# How can I see ALL global shortcuts currently active across Finder + other apps?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I've just started using Amethyst and would love to be able to use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>optn</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad[0-9]</kbd> shortcuts, but some of these aren't working and I'm assuming they're reserved by something else. I've looked in SysPrefs/Keyboard Shortcuts, as well as some of the other apps like Alfred and Keyboard Maestro, but there's nothing with those matching key combinations.

Is there a way to retrieve ALL possible keyboard shortcuts that are currently active across the entire system?

I tried [KeyCue](https://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/features.html#ShortcutTable) from a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/106862/how-can-i-easily-identify-all-keyboard-shortcuts-hotkeys-on-os-x-and-current-r) but it only retrieves Finder shorcuts.

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: No, I've ended up tracking them myself manually in a document, which is not reliable or efficient moving forward, but for now that's what I'm referring to.